# Parallelized Python program not behaving as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime

I'm new to multithreaded programming in Python, so I wrote the following script as an exercise. It simply generates a random 5000x5000 integer matrix, and computes the sum of the entries. Within the script, I wrote both single and multi-threaded versions, to do a simple speed comparison. Here is the script:

```
import random
import sys
import threading

MATRIX_SIZE = 5000

class ArraySumThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(ArraySumThread, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.total = None

    def run(self):
        tot = 0

        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            tot += self.data[i]

        self.total = tot

def generate_random_matrix(size):
    return [[random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]

def single_thread_test(size):
    matrix = generate_random_matrix(size)
    total = 0

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            total += matrix[i][j]

    return total

def multi_thread_test(size):
    matrix = generate_random_matrix(size)
    threads = [None for i in range(size)]

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        threads[i] = ArraySumThread(matrix[i])
        threads[i].start()
        threads[i].join()

    total = 0

    for thread in threads:
        total += thread.total

    return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--single' in sys.argv:
        single_thread_test(MATRIX_SIZE)

    elif '--multi' in sys.argv:
        multi_thread_test(MATRIX_SIZE)
    print 'Done.'
```

Using the UNIX `time` function to time the execution times, I get the following result:

```
$ time python thread_test.py --single
Done.

real    0m41.814s
user    0m41.575s
sys     0m0.197s
$ time python thread_test.py --multi
Done.

real    0m44.536s
user    0m43.568s
sys     0m2.539s
```

This doesn't make sense, since the multithreaded version should be much faster (I'm running this on a MacBook Pro retina, for reference). I understand that the multithreaded version does require additional time to pop in and out of the kernel to switch running threads, but even the amount of time spent in user mode is higher.

Am I forgetting something here? Do additional configurations need to be set to make use of both processors?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Because python uses the GIL, you cannot use multithreading for parallel computations like that. You'd better look into multi-process solutions for python. I have had some success with iPython (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html), but there are many more options (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing)

Answer (score 0):

This code is exclusively CPU-bound and will be run entirely within CPython, so the GIL prevents any parallelisation and in fact causes a slowdown because of the cost of context switching.

If you want to speed up this kind of numeric work, you should look into NumPy; you'll get a speed-up anyway just from that, because it offloads a lot of work to pure C, but in addition that means you should be able to parallelise it.